# How to expand nested variables in makefile

Tags: c, batch-file, makefile, gnu-make, simulink

I am using simulink to generate c-code. For the compilation of the code a generate makefile is used.

In this make file the following variable "MAKECMD" is made. This variable is used to make a `*.bat` file (how this is done I don't know yet.)

This is what is in the make file

```
SRCDIR = $(PROJECTROOT)\Implementation\Src
BLDDIR = $(PROJECTROOT)\Implementation\Bld
CFGDIR = $(PROJECTROOT)\Implementation\Cfg
BINDIR = $(BLDDIR)\bin

MAKECMD             = $(PROJECTROOT)\Tools\gmake\make.exe
```

When I look in the `*.bat` file that is generated I see that the `$(PROJECTROOT)` is not expandend.

```
set MEMORY_MODEL=BANKED
set PROJECTROOT=C:\DOCUMENT\Software\Matlab\Move\S12X_Target_R2009a
set CW_ROOT=C:\Programs\Freescale\CodeWarS12
$(PROJECTROOT)\Tools\gmake\make.exe S12X
```

What should I do so that `$(PROJECTROOT)`  wil be expandend in the `*.bat` file
so that the last line will look like this:

```
C:\DOCUMENT\Software\Matlab\Move\S12X_Target_R2009a\\Tools\gmake\make.exe S12X
```

Comment: I don't know how you generate the batch file but what you need is `%PROJECTROOT%`.

Comment: The variable should be expanded in the make file, in the batchfile the PROJECTROOT  has for some reason an other value, so %PROJECTROOT% does not work (The batch file is generateed with standard scripts from the Mathwork)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the `%PROJECTROOT%` suggestion from wOxxOm.
And added in the mathworks _make_rtw_hook.m script the creation and setting of the envorinment variable:

```
setenv('PROJECTROOT',get_param(modelName,'projectroot'))
```